# What's the significance of illusion of a person through crowd during execution scene in Mel Gibson movies?

Tags: braveheart, mel-gibson, the-passion-of-the-christ

In Braveheart (1995),  while being decapitated, Wallace sees a vision of Murron in the crowd, smiling at him.

In Passion of the Christ, While being cruxified, Jesus sees a vision of Satan in the crowd.

What's the significance of illusion of a person through crowd during execution scenes in Mel Gibson movies?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t think the two visions mentioned are related. Their only connection is that they are happening during the death of the character. It is a very common theme of seeing visions during death, pain, or great struggle. Think of the visions of Elysian Fields, also called Elysium, in movies like Gladiator.

In Braveheart, the vision is of what William Wallace wanted most. That is to see his wife waiting for him in the afterlife. It makes his death and the pain of death worthwhile. It may even ease his pain, helping him to go through it, giving him strength and courage. That is a very common theme in death scenes. In many cases, the dying person sees a loved one in the face of the person nearest to them.

In the case of Jesus, considering his lineage and abilities, the vision was probably the actual devil. Jesus has been portrayed as seeing demons, devils, and spirits that normal people could not. Seeing his adversary strengthens Jesus’s resolve, reminding him of the importance of his mission.